# Given two polytopes $P$ and $Q$, show that $(P^* \times Q^*)^* = P \oplus Q $

Tags: convex-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry

[image]

Using definitions, I got so far as to express $(P^* \times Q^*)^*$ in the following form:

> $$(P^* \times Q^*)^* = 
> \left\{\,\begin{pmatrix} z^* \\ w^* \end{pmatrix} 
> \in \mathbb{R}^{d+e}
> \,\middle|\,
> \forall \begin{pmatrix} z \\ w \end{pmatrix}
> \in (P^* \times Q^*),
> \left\langle
> \begin{pmatrix} z \\ w \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix} z^* \\ w^* \end{pmatrix} 
> \right\rangle 
> \leq 1\right\}$$

I think that I should continue trying to express $(P^* \times Q^*)^*$ in terms of $\begin{pmatrix} z^* \\ w^* \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$, but I don't know how. Or should I look at another approach? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try proving the inclusions $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ separately?

Comment: I was thinking that I'd need to do the step above first, so that given a point of one polytope, I could express it as a point of the other.

Comment: Sure you'll need to use the definitions of $(P^*\times Q^*)^*$ and $P\oplus Q$ to prove either of the inclusions.

Comment: If I have a point $t \in (P^* \times Q^*)^*$, then at the current step I can only express it in terms of a point $\begin{pmatrix} z \\ w \end{pmatrix}$ of $(P^* \times Q^*)$, but not some points $x$ of $P$ and $y$ of $Q$, and hence can't further relate it to $P \bigoplus Q$. That's where I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see this is using the duality between facets and vertices. A polytope $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ containing the origin $0$ is given by either

- vertices $v_1,\dots,v_n$ such that $ P = \operatorname{conv}(v_1,\dots,v_n) $, or
- facet normals $a_1,\dots,a_m$ such that $P = \left\{\, x \in \Bbb R^d \,\middle|\, \langle x,a_i\rangle \le 1 \text{ for $i=1,\dots,m$}\,\right\}$.

The dual polytope $P^*$ then also contains the origin in its relative interior and has vertices $a_1,\dots,a_m$ and facet normals $v_1,\dots, v_n$.

Given two such polytopes $P$ and $Q$ what can we say about the descriptions of $P\times Q$ and $P\oplus Q$ in terms of the vertices and facets of $P$ and $Q$?

- The vertices of $P\oplus Q$ are $(v,0)$ for vertices $v$ of $P$ and $(0,w)$ for vertices $w$ of $Q$,
- The facet normals of $P\times Q$ are $(a,0)$ for facet normals $a$ of $P$ and $(0,b)$ for facet normals $b$ of $Q$.

Now what are the vertices of $(P^*\times Q^*)^*$? They are the facet normals of $P^*\times Q^*$, so of the form $(v,0)$ and $(0,w)$, where $v$ and $w$ are facet normals of $P^*$ and $Q^*$, respectively. However this just means $v$ and $w$ are vertices of $P$ and $Q$, respectively. Therefore, the vertices of $(P^*\times Q^*)^*$ are exactly those of $P\oplus Q$.